# Can I measure distance between camera and an object using single image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I want to measure the distance between the camera and an object using OpenCV without giving a known distance. Is it possible? If yes, it can be done with only one image?

Comment: Can you a) calibrate your camera b) ensure the same focal length/zoom is used c) guarantee that the object is sharply focussed in the image and d) parallel to the plane of the camera's image sensor?

Answer (score 0):

Monocular depth estimation is an open issue in computer vision research. Since is not a trivial operation, you will certainly need a deep learning approach. Then, once you have your network, maybe you can run it under DNN module of openCV, if that network is supported!
About the accuracy, it depends what accuracy you need, this approach will be surely  less accurate of a RGBD camera, which has an accuracy of millimeters (depending of the distance, for example Intel Realsense D415 claims 2% error up to 4 meters).

[Here](https://paperswithcode.com/task/monocular-depth-estimation) you can find a sort of survey exactly in this field, take a look!

Comment: "You will certainly need a deep learning approach" is nonsense. The unknown is scale: if one has other ways of knowing the size of the object (or a portion of the object) in view, then one can directly calculate the distance given known camera calibration.